# Sitecore install with two separate visual studio solutions

Tags: sitecore

I'm currently reviewing an existing Sitecore installation where the two websites have separate Visual Studio solutions. I've never seen this before, and it doesn't seem like a great way of doing it. Is there any advantages at all to keep them separate or should they be merged into one solution?

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean. Are the two websites, which run on the same Sitecore site, which has two .sln files? I can't really see any reason to have 2 .sln files... and a .sln file should have any influence on the running site.

Comment: Yes, two .sln files that share the same Sitecore installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most situations, multiple SLN files will only add confusion, as adam suggested, but depending on the specific setup of how these SLN files are being used, there are benefits in specific situations.

For example, multiple SLN files is very useful if you start getting into a large number of projects, especially if not all projects apply to both websites.

Suppose you have a common business logic layer that handles integrations to back end systems for all websites.  This would be a single project referenced in both Site 1 and Site 2 SLN files.  However, you might have site-specific logic for Site 2 that is in a separate project and does not need to be visible to the team working on Site 1.  That other project would only be referenced in the Site 2 SLN file.

Comment: I gave you the answer as you provided an example on when it might be beneficial, but I agree with Adam that it is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If your project plans involve anything more than editing xslt/css/js, then I think you should merge into one solution. Sitecore has a large codebase for the CMS core, and when you get to the point where you're writing sublayouts, creating xslt extensions, extending the pipeline, creating custom field types etc you'll need to use VS to build the project. Having two solutions will just confuse this.

Best of luck! Adam

Comment: I agree with Adam, you should merge the two solutions to one. I see no reason to have two solutions..